# PHPmailer unespected HTTP ERROR 500, syntax seems ok

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have to send a mail to more users and I'm using a for loop, everything seems to work fine until i put this code under my loop, and I got HTTP ERROR 500 but I dont know why.

```
if (isset($riga_inscad[$y])) {
//PHPMAILER: inizio variabili da modificare:
$server_smtp = 'xxx';
$username_smtp= 'xxx';
$password_smtp ='xxx';
$indirizzo_mittente = 'xxx.net@xx.net';
$descrizione_mittente = 'xxxx';
$indirizzo_destinatario = 'thevar';
//fine variabili da modificare

    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

        require "src/Exception.php";
        require "src/PHPMailer.php";
        require "src/SMTP.php";

        $mail = new PHPMailer(true); 

        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
          'ssl' => array(
          'verify_peer' => false,
          'verify_peer_name' => false,
          'allow_self_signed' => true
         )
        );
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
        $mail->Host       = $server_smtp;
        $mail->Port       = 587;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; 
        $mail->Username   = $username_smtp;
        $mail->Password   = $password_smtp;
        
        $mail->setFrom($indirizzo_mittente, $descrizione_mittente);
        $mail->addAddress($indirizzo_destinatario);

        $mail->Subject = "Scadenze SEA – Riepilogo mensile";
        $mail->Body    = '';
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        if (!$mail->send())
            echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
        else
            echo "ok!";
 $mail->clearAllRecipients();

}
```

I notice that if I delete those rows:

```
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
```

The HTTP ERROR 500 goes away, but I end the for loop.
Can you tell me whats wrong pls? (Im not able to see the logs sry)

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: First, please include the for loop. I can't see it in your post. Second, why do you set `$indirizzo_destinatario = 'thevar';`? `thevar` is not an email address?

Comment: Is your code inside a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `use` statements at the top of your file. They are not really like normal code, more like compile-time directives. If you're using a really old version of PHP, it may be erroring on the `use` statements themselves – you should be running PHP 7.4 these days, 8.0 soon.

If you're running this code from inside a loop, then the fatal error is quite straightforward – if you call `require` to load the same class file more than once, you'll get a fatal error the second time.

You're enabling exceptions by passing `true` to the constructor, but you have no try/catch block, so you may get a fatal uncaught exception.

Whatever is causing the 500 error will appear in your web server's error logs. If you can't see the logs, enable error message display with `ini_set('display_errors', true);`.

Disabling TLS verification is a very bad idea. Doing it doesn't fix anything, it just hides the problem and undermines the security of your system. Fix it properly by reading [the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#certificate-verification-failure) which goes into great detail on that sbject.

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem. Its not related to this but may I ask you also why in php, when I echo an array I get "array" in result? Because its empity?

Comment: That's just how PHP converts arrays to strings. When you do an `echo` on an array, there is an implicit type conversion from array to string, which is not well-defined. If you want to see what's in an array when debugging, you're better off with `var_dump()` or `print_r()`.

Comment: when I use the command print_r() I get Array ( [0] => Array ( ) )

Comment: That means that what you passed in contains an array with 1 element which is an empty array, what you would get if you said: `$a = [[]];`